# Can't resize Google drawing

Tags: google-drawings

There is no "grab bar" in the lower right corner of the drawing as is falsely described if I Google the problem.

I'm trying to make my drawing larger but there is no way to resize the canvas area, at least no obvious way.

Comment: @rob I did not notice the comment on the answer while evaluating the edit.  I'm thinking, though, that since the answer is specific to the drawing outside of the Docs context, your edit would make the answer invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both in an existing and a newly created Google Drawing, I see the drag handle as described in the help article. [image: Google Drawing drag handle]

Since this issue seems to be related to your computer I recommend each of the following steps:

1. Make sure your browser is up to date, and among the [supported browsers listed by Google](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33864?hl=en)
2. Completely clear your browser's cookies & cache
3. Try using an Incognito window in the Chrome browser, or a Private browsing session in Firefox. These modes use their own cookies and cache, as well as often disabling extensions that could be causing the issue.
4. Try using another computer. It's possible software on your computer (antivirus, antimalware, automatic backup software, etc) is causing the issue

Comment: I understand that the grab bar is available in google drawings. I was using in-line drawing in google document where it is not available.

Comment: Then you need to edit your question so it actually says that. Your subject is "Can't resize google drawing", and Google Drawing is a kind of file within Drive. If you edit your question, I'll revise or remove my answer as needed.